# Reading and parsing files with LUA

Tags: lua

I am trying to get it to read from a file x y z coordinates into a 3d array. But it does not seem to be working.

file is located in same folder as the `.lua` script

```
-9649.481 666.4141 117.3444
-9475.624 563.4871 116.0533
-9338.459 432.295 137.4043
```

---

```
function lines_from(file)
  if not file_exists(file) then return {} end
  for line in io.lines(file) do 
    tokens = {};
    itr = 1;
    for token in string.gmatch(line, "[^%s]+") do
        tokens[ itr ] = token;
        itr = itr + 1;
    end

    x = tokens[1];
    y = tokens[2];
    z = tokens[3];
    g_lines_from[g_lines_fromCount] = { x, y, z };
    g_lines_fromCount = g_lines_fromCount + 1;

  end

end

function AddAll()
    for i = 1, g_lines_from, 1 do
        x, y, z = g_lines_from[i];
        ListBoxEntry.Create( g_lbWaypoints, "X: " .. math.floor( x ) .. ", Y: " .. math.floor( y ) .. ", Z: " .. math.floor( z ) );
    end
end

function OnAddWaypointClicked( eventID, button )
    local file = "mine1-75.txt";
    lines_from(file);
    AddAll();
end;
```

Comment: So what happens? What do you expect to get and what do you actually get? What have you attempted to debug it on your own?

Comment: Your program can be optimized a **LOT**.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following function:

```lua
function readwaypoints(filename, numberofwaypoints)
  local file = io.open(filename)
  local waypoints = {}
  for n = 1, numberofwaypoints do
    local x, y, z
    x = file:read('*n')
    y = file:read('*n')
    z = file:read('*n')
    waypoints[#waypoints+1] = {['x'] = x, ['y'] = y, ['z'] = z}
  end
  file:close()
  return waypoints
end
```

It takes a file name and the number of lines in the file. For your example file, it should return a table like this:

```lua
{[1] = {x = -9649.481, y = 666.4141, z = 117.3444},
 [2] = {x = -9475.624, y = 563.4871, z = 116.0533},
 [3] = {x = -9338.459, y = 432.295,  z = 137.4043}}
```